# How to Select all columns of a table except one

Tags: sql, postgresql

My code looks like:

```
 CREATE TABLE tableC AS
 (SELECT tableA.*,
  ST_Intersection (B.geom, A.geom) as geom2  -- generate geom
 FROM tableB, tableA
 JOIN tableB
 ON ST_Intersects (A.geom, b.geom)
 WHERE test.id = 2);
```

Now It is working but I have two columns geom and geom2!
Inside geom column I will have the new geometry based on the intersection. So how can I select tableA except the geom column?

Comment: Don't be lazy, specify the columns you do want.

Comment: ok I can do that. I thought maybe there would be an easier way to do this. Because I have a lot of columns inside the table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the table with all the columns and after that drop the `geom` column and rename the new one:

```
CREATE TABLE tableC AS
SELECT
    tableA.*,
    ST_Intersection (B.geom, A.geom) as geom2  -- generate geom
FROM
    tableA inner JOIN tableB ON ST_Intersects (A.geom, b.geom)
WHERE test.id = 2
;

alter table tableC drop column geom;
alter table tableC rename column geom2 to geom;
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way you would be able to do this would be to generate a dynamic SQL statement based on the columns within the table that excludes those you don't want.  Obviously this will be a lot more effort than simply adding in all the column names.

There are also a lot of very good reasons to never include a `select *` in a production environment, given how picky SQL often is on the number and format of columns that are returned.  By using `select *` you open yourself up to a changing query result in the future that could potentially break things.

If you have a LOT of columns and you simply don't want to manually type them all out, run the query below for your table and then format the result so you can copy/paste into your script:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'your_schema'
  AND table_name   = 'your_table'
```